# VBA - Copy a specific headers from a sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I try to copy the headers who have the cell below with "mandatory" value but my Macro stop at the first cell.
Name   Phone  Houe no    Locality
mandatory   mandatory

```
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, Lastrow1 As Long, Lastcol1 As Long
Dim mandatory As String

'Lastrow1 = Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Lastcol1 = Sheets("sheet3").Cells(1 & Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To Lastcol1

Sheets("sheet4").Activate
Lastcol2 = Sheets("sheet4").Cells(1 & Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For j = 1 To Lastcol2

If Sheets("sheet3").Cells(2, i).Value = "mandatory" Then
Sheets("sheet3").Activate
Sheets("sheet3").Cells(i, "A").Copy
Sheets("sheet4").Activate
Sheets("sheet4").Cells(j, "A").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

Next j

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i
Sheets("sheet3").Activate
Sheets("sheet3").Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(1 & Columns.Count)` should be `Cells(1 ,Columns.Count)`.  Also you may want to look at how not to use `.Activate`.  It slows the process down.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think it's working better but it put the last mandatory header in sheet3 in the cell A1 in sheet4, I think the macro only save the headers in the first cell

Comment: Are all your headers that you want copied in the first row or in the "A" column?

Comment: They are from A1 to F1 with A,B,D,E are mandatory

Comment: `Sheets("sheet3").Cells(i, "A").Copy` is telling it that all your cells to copy are in column "A" at row i.  `Sheets("sheet3").Cells(1,i).Copy` goes across the first row matching your if statement.

Comment: Yes I've changed but it still is the same issue. I show that it check only mandatory but save only in A1

Comment: it could be because the sheet 4 is empty and I have this part `Lastcol1 = Sheets("sheet3").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ` as to calculate the field ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in addition to what has been said above in the comments,  You are setting j to a column count of 0 by looking in an empty cells for the end.

use this:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Lastrow1 As Long, Lastcol1 As Long

Lastcol1 = Sheets("sheet3").Cells(1 , Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To Lastcol1
    j = Sheets("sheet4").Cells(1 , Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Column
    if j = 2 and Sheets("sheet4").Cells(1,j-1).value ="" then j=1
    If ucase(Sheets("sheet3").Cells(2, i).Value) = "MANDATORY" Then
        Sheets("sheet3").Cells(1, i).Copy Sheets("sheet4").Cells(1,j)
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i
Sheets("sheet3").Range("A1").Select
```

And by the fact that you are going cell by cell instead of copying you can just make the new cell value equal to the old cell value.

```
Sheets("sheet4").Cells(1,j).value = Sheets("sheet3").Cells(1, i).value
```

Comment: Thanks it's working, but the pasted Headers start from the B column

Comment: @java2dev Yes I forgot to shift the first one.  I have fixed the code

Comment: @java2dev if it answered your question please mark it as correct.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help